# Best way to send image through ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, image, base64, pixel

I'm writing a front end javascript application and i need to send an image on the screen which the user has uploaded to a java backend.

What is the most efficient way to send it? Should i get  the image base64 or should i store the pixels in matrix and send them

Edit: I'm not looking for code solution just recommendations on the approach to take

Comment: Base64 encoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using base64. It's easier to cache in app.

```
var image64 = null;
var xhr = $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: '/image_url/',
            data: {},
            success: function (o) {
                if (o) {
                    if (!o.err) {

                        image64 = o;
                        $('img').attr('src', 'data:image/png;base64,' + image64);
                    } else {
                        if (o.err && o.err.code === 'session_destroy') {
                            sessionDestroyed()
                        } else if (o.err){
                            alertError(o.err);
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                if (xhr.responseText != '') {
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
            }
        });
```